# Keep data synchronized between user interface and server database using jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, synchronization

I'm developing an application where the user can check and uncheck some itens in an list. He can check/uncheck repeatedly. In every action, an ajax call is made to the server, updating the information. Since the calls are not guaranteed to be made to the server in the same order they were called, how can I keep the synchronization?

I could block the user to check/uncheck until the server responded the previous action, but I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're worried about here - you should probably describe the user scenario that you're actually worried about.

If you really want to make sure that a given change sent to the server is never overwritten by an earlier change that was delivered a bit late from the same client, then you can attach a client time stamp to each ajax request and on your server and then ignore any data being set that contains an older time stamp than the last change.  This requires you to remember, on your server, the last timestamp of each change for a given piece of data from a given client.

In general, this is not a common issue.  You would need to get a combination of very rapid user changes and some odd networking that caused one request to get delayed and the next request to not get delayed.  Since both requests generally take the same network route, this would be pretty uncommon.  If you're concerned about something different than this scenario, then please describe it.

Comment: @LucasMartinsSilva - do you have any evidence that that is really something you need to protect against because it takes a bunch of server-side work to protect against it.